# Board support differences between CentOS and RHEL

Tags: centos, redhat

On SuperMicros site in OS support, there are boards that support RHEL of version X but not CentOS of version X and vice versa. I have encountered such problems my self. My question is how and why is this even possible, when CentOS is functionally identical to RHEL. And whether there is any workaround?

Comment: There should not be any difference. What type of problems have you run into?

Answer (score 0):

It should work, but the manufacturer did not tested/certified the equipment with CentOS. This is a long and pointless process because RHEL is almost identical.